# Can I burn my own installation dvd on another computer

Tags: system-installation

Can I burn my own installation dvd on another computer to install ubuntu on a newly buildt computer?

Comment: yes, yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

You can burn your own installation media on almost any computer with a disk drive. The steps required depends on the operating system you want to burn it on.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes!

Ubuntu is DRM Free since it is Mostly Open Source!